# How to get Booktab's `\cmidrule` command to play nicely together with `@{\hskip 3em}`?

Tags: tables, columns, booktabs

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \caption{Foo}
    \begin{tabular}{rr@{\hskip 3em}rr@{\hskip 6em}rr@{\hskip 3em}rr}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{Foo} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Bar}\\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-8}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Foobar}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Foobuzz}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BarFoo} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{BarFuzz} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-8}
        A & B     & C & D & E  & F & G & H\\
        \midrule
        1  & 1     &  0.01            & 0.000001  & 1    & 128       & 1 & 1--1 \\
        2  & 3     &  0.1             & 0.000003  & 2    & 256       & 2 & 1--2 \\
        3  & 1     &  1               & 0.00001   & 3    & 512       & 3 & 1--3 \\
        4  & 3     &  10              & 0.00003   & 4    & 1024      &   &      \\
        5  & 1     &  100             & 0.0001    & 5    & 2048      &   &      \\
     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have two major groups Foo and Bar which columns I want to separate with some column space. I then in these groups have subgroups, Foobar, FooBuzz, BarFoo and BarFuzz that I also want to separate a bit. I then want to use a line underneath to show what keeps together. Now, it seems that the `\cmidrule` command of does not see my columns spacing as space between the columns but as part of the columns if you see what I mean. In fact it seems like the `\multicolumn` also makes this error. How can I make space between columns that will be honoured as space between columns by `\cmidrule` and `\multicolumn`?

Comment: In addition to Bernard's answer, I often add blank columns (extra `&`) just to house space. Much easier to control in relation to midrules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to incorporate the intercolumn spacing *also* in the relevant `\multicolumn`s, and take it into account in the values for the trimming of `\cmidrule`. Here is a possible code \ I loaded the `caption` package to have a sensible spacing between caption above and table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \caption{Foo}
    \begin{tabular}{rr@{\hskip 3em}rr@{\hskip 6em}rr@{\hskip 3em}rr}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{4}{c@{\hskip 6em}}{Foo} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Bar}\\
        \cmidrule(lr{5.75em}){1-4}\cmidrule(l{-0.15em}r){5-8}
        \multicolumn{2}{c@{\hskip 3em}}{Foobar} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{\hskip 6em}}{Foobuzz} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{\hskip 3.5em}}{BarFoo} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c!{\hskip 0.5em}}{BarFuzz} \\
        \cmidrule(lr{2.75em}){1-2}\cmidrule(lr{5.85em}){3-4}\cmidrule(l{-0.15em}r{2.75em}){5-6}\cmidrule(l{-0.05em}r){7-8}
        A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H\\
        \midrule
        1 & 1 & 0.01 & 0.000001 & 1 & 128 & 1 & 1--1 \\
        2 & 3 & 0.1 & 0.000003 & 2 & 256 & 2 & 1--2 \\
        3 & 1 & 1 & 0.00001 & 3 & 512 & 3 & 1--3 \\
        4 & 3 & 10 & 0.00003 & 4 & 1024 & & \\
        5 & 1 & 100 & 0.0001 & 5 & 2048 & & \\
     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hm isn't Barfuzz too far to the right compared to the line underneath?

Comment: @jonalv: You're right. I hadn't taken care of all details. Hopefully, it's fixed now (values found by trial and error).